# BCP: Importing data with keeping identity values causes "Invalid character value for cast specification"

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, bcp

I've got a problem while copying data from SQL Server 2012 to Azure DB.
Here I'm listing the steps I have made.

1. Created `.dat` and `.xml` format files as follows:

   `bcp.exe dbo.user_sayti out "c:\\dbo.user_sayti.dat" -w -k -Slocalhost -dsource_db -Uuser -Ppwd`

   `bcp.exe dbo.user_sayti format nul -f "c:\\dbo.user_sayti.xml" -w -x -Slocalhost -dsource_db -Uuser -Ppwd`

   [dbo.user_sayti.dat](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwaB7T2TolRFUWM4Z0pEM3FoYXc/edit?usp=sharing)
   [dbo.user_sayti.xml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwaB7T2TolRFenloOXREaU1iMzA/edit?usp=sharing)
2. Made an attempt to copy them to Azure DB with keeping identity values:

   `bcp.exe dbo.user_sayti in "c:\\dbo.user_sayti.dat" -E -f "c:\\dbo.user_sayti.xml" -Sserver.database.windows.net -dtarget_db -Uuser -Ppwd`

   And have got **"`Invalid character value for cast specification`"** error.
   I don't understand why, because the `.dat` file contains value `127` for the identity column `id (PK, int, not NULL)` and the number of values matches the number of rows.
3. Then I've tried the same command without `-E` and the process finished successfully (there is the only row in this particular table and it appeared in the `target_db` with identity column value = `1`).

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `-f` parameter (schema definition) with `-w` solved that stupid problem :)